# DateTime What if Value is NULL

Tags: c#, .net

```
UpdateDate([Optional, DefaultParameterValue(null)] object dateTime)
```

I Have Method Like this and i have to call this method

```
UpdateDate(DSSID.Tables[0].Rows[0][0].ToString())
```

if in case in database if there is NULL  value then function `UpdateDate(date)` will throw the error...

I tried parsing.. whaty is the best solution to handle such situation?

Comment: Show `UpdateDate()` method body, I feel the problem that date field is defined as not nullable (`DateTime` but not `DateTime?`)

Comment: Why are you passing in an `object` type and not a `DateTime`?

Comment: MSDN Handling Null values... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172138(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can test the result to see if it is null and then take appropriate action:

```
if (DSSID.Tables[0].Rows[0][0] == DBNull.Value)
```